# Display items into Spring MVC table

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have this Endpoint:

```
@Controller
public class FileImportsController {

    private EntityImportRequestsService entityImportRequestsService;

    @Autowired
    public FileImportsController(EntityImportRequestsService entityImportRequestsService) {
        this.entityImportRequestsService = entityImportRequestsService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/imported_files")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model) {
        List<EntityImportRequestsTable> listProducts = entityImportRequestsService.findAll();
        System.out.println("Size is " + listProducts.size());

        model.addAttribute("listProducts", listProducts);
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "EntityImportRequests")
public class EntityImportRequestsTable implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "requestId")
    private String requestId;

    @Column(name = "transactionGroupId")
    private Integer transactionGroupId;

    @Column(name = "requestXmlSourceFile")
    private String requestXmlSourceFile;

    @Column(name = "createdOn")
    private LocalDateTime createdOn;
}
```

Web page index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Files Manager</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
  <h1>Files List</h1>
  <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <tr th:each="item : ${listProducts}">
      <td th:text="${item.requestId}"/>
      <td th:text="${item.transactionGroupId}"/>
      <td th:text="${item.requestXmlSourceFile}"/>
      <td th:text="${item.createdOn}"/>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the page data is not displayed. What is the proper way to display the data rows from `listProducts`?
When I make a call to the rest controller directly I get this output:

```
Hibernate: select entityimpo0_.requestId as requesti1_0_, entityimpo0_.createdOn as createdo2_0_, entityimpo0_.requestXmlSourceFile as requestx3_0_, entityimpo0_.transactionGroupId as transact4_0_ from integration.EntityImportRequests entityimpo0_
Size is 69
```

As you can see the list is not empty. I have 69 items.

Comment: Have you ever tried `spring.jpa.open-in-view=true`? And you can print each product  along with size to provide more debug information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this.
Just make sure that your listProducts is not empty in your controller.

```
<tr th:each="product: ${listProducts}">
    <td th:text="${product.requestId}" />
    <td th:text="${product.name}" />
    <td th:text="${product.price}" />
</tr>
```

Or whatever fields your product entity has next to the name, price, etc.

Comment: I get employ table row. Maybe I need to specify somehow the GET path `/imported_files`?

Comment: That is probably because entityImportRequestsService.findAll(); is returning data from employee table, call the proper method, store that result in a variable, and pass it to the model.

Comment: I put some debug messages into the controller. Looks like the controller is not called at all. How I can call it from the html page.

Comment: Your controller is called depending on the URL which you defined in your @GetMapping, in your situation it would be for example localhost:8080/appname/imported_files, that URL will trigger a method that will trigger a controller that you shared, and that method will return a view.
If you are getting some out from iterating over listProducts, your controller is being called.

Comment: As you can see from the html code I don't call it anywhere. How I can implement this API call?

Comment: I already told you, the url will trigger a method from your controller that will return a view and you transfer the data using Model object.

Comment: call a method, store a result in a variable and pass that value to model, then you can use that model value to iterate over that in your thymeleaf template

Comment: Can you update your answer, please?

Comment: update to what? Your question is " proper way to display the data rows from listProducts "

Comment: Update it with code how to call the endpoint.

Comment: Your question is not about the endpoint Peter, your question is about displaying rows, if you have a different question, open a different question.

Comment: try to print the ${listProducts} in the page. You should see if it's filled

Comment: What url are you using to open the page?